# Power BI conditional formatting - matrix and multiple conditions

Tags: matrix, powerbi, powerquery, dashboard

I have this issue in Power BI I can't figure out. I have a sharepoint excel sheet (I can't edit) loaded in PBI desktop.
It's a matrix/table, with projects, their SLAs and weekly actual values. The values need to be colour coded for each week and value, based on if we hit the SLA target or not that week.
But some values are "lower the better", some are "higher the better".

[How the matrix looks like in PBI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Og88k.png)

Also there are 53 week columns and I can't figure out how to apply conditional formatting on all these in style as picture shows.
Thank you so much for any help!

I tried applying conditional formatting on columns, but, there are too many columns and also it allows me to either apply "lower the better" or "higher the better" logic.
There must be a better way

| Project | SLA | Target | Unit | W1 | W2 | W3 | W4 | W5 | ..... | W53 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Amazon | Calls answered | 80 | % | 90 | 70 | 85 |  |  |  |  |
| Amazon | Sales closed | 70 | % | 75 | 80 | 90 |  |  |  |  |
| Amazon | Sick hours* | 465 | h | 200 | 560 | 540 |  |  |  |  |
| Aldi | Calls answered | 80 | % | 70 | 89 | 90 |  |  |  |  |
| Aldi | Emails answered | 90 | % | 80 | 81 | 82 |  |  |  |  |
| Aldi | Avg time to handle* | 300 | sec | 360 | 205 | 200 |  |  |  |  |
| Tesco | Sales closed | 70 | % | 50 | 76 | 79 |  |  |  |  |
| Tesco | Emails answered | 90 | % | 90 | 91 | 93 |  |  |  |  |
| Tesco | Chats answered | 90 | % | 95 | 94 | 95 |  |  |  |  |
| Tesco | Avg time to handle calls* | 350 | sec | 360 | 460 | 340 |  |  |  |  |

[Conditional formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02QZH.png)

[Measure error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8fD5.png)

Comment: Can you update your question with more details on your data model. What does the data table(s) look like? How are you handling unique SLAs per Project? On your question specifically, you will need a new measure that will be used for the Conditional Formatting.

Comment: @SamNseir This is exactly what the table looks like, the source is only one table. This is like an 'SLA overview' so different SLA's for different projects. I was thinking about using a measure, but how to avoid having to create one for each week because there are 53 of them?

Comment: For clarification, you one table has a column for each week (1..53)? Update your question with a few sample rows of your one data table in [markdown format](https://tabletomarkdown.com/).

Comment: Yes, so every week of year 2024 there are new data in the columns, in this format:

Comment: Did the below answer your question? Any further help needed?

Comment: I was off because I got the flu, trying it today! 

Comment: I finished all the steps, just got stuck with the last one :( How did you format the custom measure, I keep getting "If value >= .. and ... then" when I try the conditional formatting, it doesn't show the "If value is *text*" option for me.

Comment: See [Color by rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-conditional-table-formatting#color-by-rules)

Comment: I checked and I can't get the conditional formatting to display the newly created measure as text. Maybe if I try and hardcode DEX colours in the measure, would it work? Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Check that the CF measure has Data type as Text.

Comment: I checked the data type and went back to the conditional formatting, it doesn't recognise it as Text for some reason. I edited the post to show screenshots at the bottom.

Comment: I take it back, I'm an idiot. I didn't format values as numbers. Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: Great, if all good, please help mark the answer as Accepted for the benefit of all (the checkmark below the voting buttons of the answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, for your Matrix, you would have one measure for the Values, and another for Conditional Formatting. You would also have a column for W1...W53 that you would use in the Matrix Columns.

For the above, you will need to re-shape your data model. In PowerQuery I would split your one table into two tables.

1. Add an Index column to your table - this will be used as a "Metric Id" so feel free to rename that column.
2. Reference that query, into a new query and drop all the Wx columns. Name the query `SLA`.
3. Reference query in 1 again, into a new query, drop all columns except the Wx columns and the Index/ID column. Then right-click on the `Metric Id` header and select `Unpivot other columns`. In the Formula bar, rename `Attribute` to `Week`. Name the query `SLA Value`.
4. Right-click on the query in step 1, and de-select enable load.
5. Create a new Blank Query with the following. Name the query `Week`:

```
let
  Source = List.Generate(() => 1, each _ < 54, each _ + 1, each "W" & Text.From(_)),
  #"Converted to table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
  #"Renamed columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Converted to table", {{"Column1", "Week"}})
in
  #"Renamed columns"
```

You should hopefully have three tables looking like this:

**Table/Query: `SLA`** (from step 2 above)

| Project | SLA | Target | Unit | Metric Id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

**Table/Query: `SLA Value`** (from step 3 above)

| Metric Id | Week | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | W1 | 90 |
| 1 | W2 | 70 |

**Table/Query: `Week`** (from step 5 above)

| Week |
| --- |
| W1 |
| W2 |

Close & Apply.

Create relationships so your model looks like:  [image]

Essentially, `SLA Value` is your Fact table, and the other two are your Dimension tables.

Create a measure that we'll use for the Conditional Formatting:

```
CF SLA Value = 
  var t = MIN('SLA'[Target])
  var v = MIN('SLA Value'[Value])
  var lowerBetter = CONTAINSSTRING(SELECTEDVALUE('SLA'[SLA]), "~*")
  return IF(
    lowerBetter,
    IF(v <= t, "G", "R"),
    IF(v >= t, "G", "R")
  )
```

Construct the Matrix:

- `Rows`: from the `SLA` table, add: Project, SLA, Unit, Target
- `Columns`: from the `Week` table, add: Week
- `Values`: from the `SLA Value` table, add: Value

Then expand all rows.
In the visual properties, under Row headers:

- Switch off `+/- icons`
- Switch off `Stepped layout`

And switch off `Column subtotals` and `Row subtotals`.

Under `Cell elements`, add Background color Conditional Formatting with the following:

[image]

Should hopefully give you a matrix like this:

[image]

---

The other alternative without changing your one table or data model, is to create 53 measures, one for each column, that will be used for the Conditional Formatting rule. And then applying these 53 times.